# EFCircularSlider set currentValue programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, circular-slider

I am using EFCircularSlider IOS component and I would like to change its value to apply on the interface. Only setting the value to currentValue is not worling.

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand your question, is  [circularSlider setCurrentValue:10.0f] not setting the value for you?

Comment: It is setting the value, but its not applying to the view

Comment: You did something wrong, and its hard to know what without you explaining a bit more.. I downloaded it myself and all worked great. Try downloading the Demo and look what is different to your code  https://github.com/eliotfowler/EFCircularSlider

Comment: @PiratM i was using the latest version on cocoapods. The latest version is really working! Tranks

Comment: That happens when you copy the Pod from the Readme file in Github. Change it to:
pod "EFCircularSlider", "> 0.1.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using cocoapods latest version (0.1.0). Dowloading the latest revision it worked.

See: https://github.com/eliotfowler/EFCircularSlider/issues/15